# How to restrict a cross point bin based on the sum of crossed coverpoints? and what's the meaning of binsof?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-coverage

I got two 3-bit signals `a` and `b` with legal values 0-4.

I'm trying to make a cross point where I only consider the coverage if the sum also is in the range 0-4. What is the preferred way to do that? I have a solution that seems to work, but I have guessed in some places ...

```
covergroup CG_operands @(posedge clk);
   coveproint a { illegal_bins hi = {[5:$]}; }
   coveproint b { illegal_bins hi = {[5:$]}; }
   cross a, b { illegal_bins hi = binsof(a) with (a + b > 4) }
endgroup
```

What does the `binsof(a)` part do? If I change it to `binsof(a) && binsof(b)` nothing seems to change in the coverage report. Is it possible to skip the `binsof` part completely?

Also can I make the coverpoint conditions look more like the with-condition of the cross using `> 4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `binsof` operator is used to select a subset of bins from a `coverpoint`. But since you are selecting the entire coverpoint a, there's no difference between using `binsof(b)` or `binsof(a) && binsof(b)`. You could write

```
ab: cross a, b { ignore_bins hi = ab with (a + b > 4); }
```

Comment: So what would happen if there was also a third coverpoint that I didn't use in my cross? `coverpoint c ...`

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please ask as a separate question.

Comment: I guess I still just don't understand the `binsof` part, I will experiment a bit and get back with another question if needed, thanks Dave.

Comment: Imagine instead of coverpoints, we had 10 rows and 10 columns. If you cross them, you get 100 elements. Now if you do a selection of the cross from all rows, you still get 100 elements. A selection of all columns of the cross also gives you 100 elements. So if you AND or OR both selections together, you still get 100 elements. 
Now separate the coverpoints in half into hi and low bins. Using the same cross, you can select `binsof (rows.lo)`. You have selected 50 elements. `binsof(rows.lo) && binsof(cols.hi)` would be 25 elements, and ORing them would be selecting 75 elements.